# Automatically build allure report after test completion

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, allure

I am trying to figure out how to automatically build the allure report after my TestNG suite has completed. I know its possible to create the report by running `mvn site` manually after the test, but it would be great if it was possible for the reports to be automatically be generated. Below is the allure config from my pom.xml

```
                <properties>
                  <testng.congig>${selenium.suite}</testng.congig>
                  <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
                  <allure.version>1.4.3</allure.version>
                </properties>

              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>target\test-classes\${testng.congig}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
              <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
              <version>${allure.version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <reporting>
             <excludeDefaults>false</excludeDefaults>
             <plugins>
              <plugin>
                 <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                 <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>{latest.version}</version>
               </plugin>
             </plugins>
           </reporting>
```

Comment: Interestingly, so different than ExtentReports which builds the report while the tests are running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The test execution and site generation run in a different life cycle.

The default lifecycle differs from the site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

What you can do is just chain the commands: e.g. `mvn install site` or `mvn deploy site-deploy` if you plan to make the site available somewhere.
This will run the tests and then execute a site generation.

The maven goals relate to a phase in that lifecycle. `mvn package` will execute all plugins bound to one of the phases until `package` phase. Since site generation has its own lifecycle I would not bind the plugin execution to one of the phases of the default lifecycle. Reporting plugins often rely on a finished build.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Add dependencies Allure Builder Reporter into pom.xml
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.allure/allure-report-builder/2.1

Step 2: Add this code:

```
// It will generate the Allure Report folder.
  new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("target/allure-report")).unpackFace();
  new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("target/allure-report")).processResults(new 
  File("target/allure-results"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate Allure report automatically.
Please follow the below steps:

1. Add dependency of Allure command line with version 2.8.1
   [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-commandline/2.8.1][1]
2. Create allure.properties file under src/test/resources and set below values
   allure.results.directory=target/allure-results
   It means that,when the allure results generate under target folder
3. copy the below code use accordingly.

   ```
   import io.qameta.allure.Extension;
   import io.qameta.allure.ReportGenerator;
   import io.qameta.allure.allure1.Allure1Plugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.allure2.Allure2Plugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.category.CategoriesPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.category.CategoriesTrendPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.context.FreemarkerContext;
   import io.qameta.allure.context.JacksonContext;
   import io.qameta.allure.context.MarkdownContext;
   import io.qameta.allure.context.RandomUidContext;
   import io.qameta.allure.core.*;
   import io.qameta.allure.duration.DurationPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.duration.DurationTrendPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.environment.Allure1EnvironmentPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.executor.ExecutorPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.history.HistoryPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.history.HistoryTrendPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.idea.IdeaLinksPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.influxdb.InfluxDbExportPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.launch.LaunchPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.mail.MailPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.owner.OwnerPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.prometheus.PrometheusExportPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.retry.RetryPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.retry.RetryTrendPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.severity.SeverityPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.status.StatusChartPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.suites.SuitesPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.summary.SummaryPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.tags.TagsPlugin;
   import io.qameta.allure.timeline.TimelinePlugin;
   import java.nio.file.Path;
   import java.nio.file.Paths;


   private void onGenerateAllureReport() {
           Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       final List<Extension> extensions = Arrays.asList(new JacksonContext(), new MarkdownContext(), new FreemarkerContext(), new RandomUidContext(), new MarkdownDescriptionsPlugin(), new RetryPlugin(), new RetryTrendPlugin(), new TagsPlugin(), new SeverityPlugin(), new OwnerPlugin(), new IdeaLinksPlugin(), new CategoriesPlugin(), new CategoriesTrendPlugin(), new HistoryPlugin(), new HistoryTrendPlugin(), new DurationPlugin(), new DurationTrendPlugin(), new StatusChartPlugin(), new TimelinePlugin(), new SuitesPlugin(), new TestsResultsPlugin(), new AttachmentsPlugin(), new MailPlugin(), new InfluxDbExportPlugin(), new PrometheusExportPlugin(), new SummaryPlugin(), new ExecutorPlugin(), new LaunchPlugin(), new Allure1Plugin(), new Allure1EnvironmentPlugin(), new Allure2Plugin(), new ReportWebPlugin());
                       Configuration configuration = (new ConfigurationBuilder()).fromExtensions(extensions).build();
                       Path resultDi = Paths.get("target/allure-results");
                       Path outDir = Paths.get("target/allure-report");
                       new ReportGenerator(configuration).generate(outDir, resultDi);
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           });
       }~~~
   ```
4. First way to use- Implement SuiteInializer Listner and paste the code onFinish method. and on Start Method please paste below code for delete old allure results.
   `FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("target/allure-results"));`
5. Second Way: You can use cucumber hooks.